# Site doesn't open pages completely with mobile and incognito mode

Tags: wordpress, web, incognito-mode

I just published a new page on my site but it is not showing all tab pages in incognito window. Similarly, it is also not opening fulling in mobile view. However, only header and footer displays. My site is archiecoogan dot co dot uk. I just installed SSL certificate yesterday and now having these issues.

If it is about hosting account files then please guide me.

Comment: Do you have any code or config files you can share?

Comment: Its a wordpress site. However, I don't see this issue from yesterday.